# After ":set paste" executed "insert mode's remaps" stop working - VIM (iTerm2)

Tags: macos, vim, iterm2

I have this remaps in my **.vimrc**

```
inoremap <C-d> <C-o>de
inoremap <C-k> <BS>
inoremap <C-l> <ESC>
inoremap <C-j> <CR>
```

They does work great, but after **:set paste** they stop working properly and I'm getting this `^L` when I press `<c-l>` and `^@` when `<c-j>` is pressed.

If I execute **:set nopaste** it starts working again as expected.

Is there a way to make it work even with **:set paste**? or **:set nopaste** after `CMD+V` is pressed?

Comment: 'paste' is not meant to be a permanent setting because it prevents mappings from working, among other things. For an easy way to toggle the option, see `:help 'pastetoggle'`

Comment: @Heptite Thank you very much for your comment. I didn't know about pastetoggle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, as explained in `:help 'paste'`, mappings don't work in "paste" mode.

If you need to copy/paste stuff from/to Vim to/from other programs, get yourself [a proper Vim](https://github.com/macvim-dev/macvim/releases) with clipboard support, use `"+y` and `"+p` and forget `:set [no]paste`.

Comment: @romaini Thank you very much for your answer.