# Make Shift+Insert work in Insert Mode with "set paste" active

Tags: windows, vim, shortcuts, gvim, clipboard

I have a Windows client with gvim for Windows 7.4. I want Shift+Insert to work as "Paste", so I added the following settings to ~/_vimrc:

```
nnoremap <S-Insert> "+gP 
inoremap <S-Insert> <Esc>"+gP<CR>i
```

This makes S+Insert work properly (paste the clipboard contents) in the following cases:

- Normal mode.
- Insert mode with `:set nopaste` active.

But when Shift+Insert is pressed in Insert mode with `:set paste`, then instead of the clipboard contents, the string `<S-Insert>` is inserted into the document.

I found this similar question ([After ":set paste" executed "insert mode's remaps" stop working - VIM (iTerm2)](https://superuser.com/questions/984332/after-set-paste-executed-insert-modes-remaps-stop-working-vim-iterm2)) but related to iTerm2 (it's 1 year old) but I cannot believe there is no solution in Vim for this.

Thanks.

Comment: The whole point of `:set paste` is to not expand mappings. It would be a bug, if the mapping worked.

Comment: Thanks for answering. It's OK if that's the expected behaviour, but ... is there any other way (no mappings) to achieve what I expect (`Shift+Insert` = paste contents) in `paste mode`?

Comment: doesn'T Shift+Insert do this by default and you don't need paste mode at all?

Comment: When I'm in insert mode, it does not work. It just inserts the `<S-Insert>` string, but I want to behave like Shift+Insert in the terminal (paste clipboard contents).

Comment: This is gvim right? You shouldn't need paste mode there at all.